# Oracle : How to get Last DDL Updated Time

Tags: oracle

I have tried the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM all_objects
```

But it also update LAST_DDL_TIME column of above table whenever any table grant is given any other schema.

I want Last DDL update time for table Alter only.

Comment: Which DDL commands do you mean? Are you including TRUNCATE, MOVE, SHRINK, adding a new index, dropping an index ... ?

Comment: You probably need a DDL trigger and a custom table for this.

Comment: Thanks @JeffreyKemp...Your solution is working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ketan, I think DDL Triggers will solve your problems.

Find out more on this : http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ddl_triggers.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you use trigger to monitor DDL, you are essentially replicating functionality already provided through Oracle Auditing.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_4007.htm

There is 10g-related guidance here: https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/auditing-10gr2

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT object_name, object_type, last_ddl_time
FROM dba_objects 
WHERE owner = <<table owners name>>
AND object_name = 'yourTableName'
```

Comment: That information is not different from the one visible through `all_objects` which is does not contain what Ketan wants

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name:- Then I think OP has to create some timestamp column in his/her table and add the timestamp value when s/he is altering the value. Isn't it?

Comment: That would be per row, not per table.